# overridePendingTransition in API Level 4

Tags: android

My Application minSdkVersion is 4.I want to use overridePendingTransition method for animation.how to?
Is there any Compatibale package for animation in API Levels less than 5?

Comment: why do you bother about those 0.4%? http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: @tabbykitten Don't Remove Question please :D

Comment: ok, the answer is do not go for default app framework. Have only one activity and it gonna be FragmentActivity from compatibility library(it's level 4). Manage your own screen stacks, and your own animation, either with default animations or http://nineoldandroids.com/.

Comment: @tabbykitten So please post your comment as answer and add to it 'it's not possible in normal way and with support package'then i tick it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in normal way.

Anyway there are non normal ways to do :) the answer is do not go for default app framework. Have only one activity and it gonna be FragmentActivity from compatibility library(it's level 4). Manage your own screen stacks, and your own animation, either with default animations or nineoldandroids.com.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Try adding this code and see if it works , Because android supports compiling in higher and running in lower version

And one more thing, try keeping `minSdkVersion` to atleast 7, because `very very very very less` people use API 4